# Tower of Hanoi - Why are my functions not updating the pointers correctly?

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, data-structures

First, I defined most of my functions recursively to practice recursion.

When I looked at the debugger, I noticed several things:

1. My functions swap() is NOT updating the pointer variables in the tower_of_hanoi() function
2. My functions push() and pop() are not handling the exceptions.
3. Since my swap() function is not updating my pointers, the base case is never reached.

I tried to catch several exceptions, but I notice that it still did not help.  I was expecting each of the swap() calls to update the pointers, but it is not properly updating the pointer variables.  So the height of my 3rd tower is ALWAYS a height of 0, and the problem is never solved.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct disk {
    int value;
    disk* top;
};

// Initializing Structures
disk* tower_1 = NULL;
disk* tower_2 = NULL;
disk* tower_3 = NULL;
disk* tower_1_top = NULL;
disk* tower_2_top = NULL;
disk* tower_3_top = NULL;

// Function 
disk* push(disk* tower, int value); // push (disk* tower to push into, int value we want the disk to have)
void push_helper(disk* current_disk, disk* new_disk); 
disk* pop(disk* tower); // pop(disk* tower to pop off top disk)
disk* top_disk(disk* tower);
int tower_height(disk* tower);
int tower_height_recursive(disk* tower);
void display_tower(disk* tower);
void display_tower_recursive(disk* tower);
void swap_disk(disk* swap_tower_a, disk* swap_tower_b);
void tower_of_hanoi_solver(disk* tower1, disk* tower2, disk* tower3, int max_height);

int main()
{
    char user_continue = 'y';

    tower_1 = push(tower_1, 4);
    tower_1 = push(tower_1, 2);
    tower_1 = push(tower_1, 1);
    tower_1_top = top_disk(tower_1);

    cout << "Tower 1: \n";
    display_tower_recursive(tower_1);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Tower 1 Height: " << tower_height_recursive(tower_1) << endl;
    cout << "Top of Tower 1: " << tower_1_top->value << endl << endl;


    cout << "Tower 2: \n";
    display_tower_recursive(tower_2);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Tower Height: " << tower_height_recursive(tower_2) << endl << endl;

    cout << "Tower 3: \n";
    display_tower_recursive(tower_3);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Tower Height: " << tower_height_recursive(tower_3) << endl << endl;



    // Call to do the Tower of Hanoi game
    int max_height_tower = tower_height_recursive(tower_1);
    tower_of_hanoi_solver(tower_1, tower_2, tower_3,max_height_tower);

    //Final Towers After Game
    cout << "Final Towers: \n\n";

    cout << "Tower 1: \n";
    display_tower_recursive(tower_1);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Tower Height: " << tower_height_recursive(tower_1) << endl << endl;

    cout << "Tower 2: \n";
    display_tower_recursive(tower_2);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Tower Height: " << tower_height_recursive(tower_2) << endl << endl;

    cout << "Tower 3: \n";
    display_tower_recursive(tower_3);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Tower Height: " << tower_height_recursive(tower_3) << endl << endl;


    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}

disk* push(disk* tower, int value)
{
    disk* p_new_disk = new disk;
    p_new_disk->value = value;
    p_new_disk->top = NULL;

    if (p_new_disk == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (tower == NULL)
    {
        tower = p_new_disk;
        return tower;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (tower->top == NULL)
        {
            tower->top = p_new_disk;
            return tower;
        }
        else if (tower->top->top == NULL)
        {
            tower->top->top = p_new_disk;
        }
        else
        {
            push(tower->top->top, value);
        }
        //push_helper(tower, p_new_disk);
    }
    

    return tower;
}

void push_helper(disk* current_disk, disk* new_disk)
{
    if (current_disk -> top == NULL)
    {
        current_disk->top = new_disk;
    }
    else
    {
        push_helper(current_disk->top, new_disk);
    }
}

disk* pop(disk* tower)
{
    if (tower == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (tower->top == NULL) 
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (tower->top != NULL && tower->top->top == NULL)
        {
            disk* p_temp = tower->top;
            tower->top = NULL;
            delete p_temp;
            return tower;
        }
        else
        {
            return pop(tower->top);
        }
    }

}

disk* top_disk(disk* tower)
{

    if (tower == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (tower->top == NULL)
    {
        return tower;
    }
    else
    {
        return top_disk(tower->top);
    }
}

int tower_height(disk* tower)
{
    disk* current_disk = tower;
    int count = 0;

    while (current_disk != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        current_disk = current_disk->top;
    }

    return count;
}

int tower_height_recursive(disk* tower)
{
    disk* current_disk = tower;

    if (current_disk == NULL) // Handles if the(current_disk has NO disks.
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + tower_height_recursive(current_disk->top);
    }
}

void display_tower(disk* tower)
{
    disk* current_disk = tower;
    while (current_disk != NULL)
    {
        cout << current_disk->value << endl;
        current_disk = current_disk->top;
    }
}

void display_tower_recursive(disk* tower)
{
    if (tower == NULL)
    {
        cout << "None!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << tower->value << endl;
        display_tower_recursive(tower->top);
    }

}

void swap_disk(disk* swap_tower_a, disk* swap_tower_b)
{
    disk* top_tower_a = top_disk(swap_tower_a);
    disk* top_tower_b = top_disk(swap_tower_b);

    if (swap_tower_a == NULL && swap_tower_b == NULL) 
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (swap_tower_a != NULL && swap_tower_b == NULL)
    {
        swap_tower_b = push(swap_tower_b, top_tower_a->value);
        swap_tower_a = pop(swap_tower_a);
    }
    else
    {
        if (top_tower_a != NULL && top_tower_b != NULL) {
            if (top_tower_a->value < top_tower_b->value)
            {
                swap_tower_b = push(swap_tower_b, top_tower_a->value);
                swap_tower_a = pop(swap_tower_a);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    
}

void tower_of_hanoi_solver(disk* tower1, disk* tower2, disk* tower3, int max_height)
{
    int tower_1_height = tower_height_recursive(tower1);

    // Tower 1
    if (tower_1_height % 2 == 0)
    {
        swap_disk(tower1, tower2);
    }
    else
    {
        swap_disk(tower1, tower3);
    }

    // Tower 2
    swap_disk(tower2, tower3);
    swap_disk(tower2, tower1);

    // Tower 3
    swap_disk(tower3, tower2);
    swap_disk(tower3, tower1);

    int tower_3_height = tower_height_recursive(tower3);

    if (tower_3_height == max_height)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        tower_of_hanoi_solver(tower1, tower2, tower3,  max_height);
    }


}
```

I first defined my pointers to be global for the towers - tower_1, tower_2, and tower_3 - so my entire program can manipulate and change the value.  I did not put the word 'const' in front of them.

I wanted the tower_of_hanoi_solver() function to use the swap() function, but my debugger says my pointers are not being updated.  Here's the code for the swap() and tower_of_hanoi_solver() functions

```
void swap_disk(disk* swap_tower_a, disk* swap_tower_b)
{
    disk* top_tower_a = top_disk(swap_tower_a);
    disk* top_tower_b = top_disk(swap_tower_b);

    if (swap_tower_a == NULL && swap_tower_b == NULL) 
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (swap_tower_a != NULL && swap_tower_b == NULL)
    {
        swap_tower_b = push(swap_tower_b, top_tower_a->value);
        swap_tower_a = pop(swap_tower_a);
    }
    else
    {
        if (top_tower_a != NULL && top_tower_b != NULL) {
            if (top_tower_a->value < top_tower_b->value)
            {
                swap_tower_b = push(swap_tower_b, top_tower_a->value);
                swap_tower_a = pop(swap_tower_a);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    
}

void tower_of_hanoi_solver(disk* tower1, disk* tower2, disk* tower3, int max_height)
{
    int tower_1_height = tower_height_recursive(tower1);

    // Tower 1
    if (tower_1_height % 2 == 0)
    {
        swap_disk(tower1, tower2);
    }
    else
    {
        swap_disk(tower1, tower3);
    }

    // Tower 2
    swap_disk(tower2, tower3);
    swap_disk(tower2, tower1);

    // Tower 3
    swap_disk(tower3, tower2);
    swap_disk(tower3, tower1);

    int tower_3_height = tower_height_recursive(tower3);

    if (tower_3_height == max_height)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        tower_of_hanoi_solver(tower1, tower2, tower3,  max_height);
    }


}
```

Why is the swap() function not updating the pointers in the tower_of_hanoi_solver() function - and hence the original pointers as well?

Comment: Side notes for swapping there is [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), there is no need for using pointers (unless required by your excercise).  Replace `NULL` with `nullptr`. If you need a stack (or stacks) you can use  [std::stack<disk>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack). Avoid using `using namespace std;`. And really try to avoid global  variables.

Comment: I''m just guessing here, but you wrote all of this code without any testing in between? Don't do that. For any large and complex problem, break it down into smaller and less complex problems, and so on until nothing can be broken down any more. Then solve each small and simple problem one by one, building and testing before continuing with the next. When there's a problem, it's easy to know what causes it, to debug it, and to solve it.

Comment: Apart from the `cout`, this code is C language to me. C++ has much more to offer than raw pointers to plain `struct`.

Comment: parameters are passed by value, pointers are no exception. None of your functions can modify any of the pointers value that it gets passed

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I know C++ has those additional libraries, but I just want to use pointers to practice using pointers.

Comment: I did do some testing in between.  That is why I broke up the functions into push(), pop(), swap() and the others.  I tested the push(), pop(), tower_height() separately with basic programs.  When I implemented them all together, then that is where the problems began.

Comment: its not about additional libraries, but about writing idomatic code, and idiomatic C++ has (almost) no raw pointers. If you want to practice you should practice the right thing. From the top of my head I dont know a good exercise for raw pointers (at least not for a beginner). Its a long way you need to go before you actually need one.

Comment: before pointers you need to learn about pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value

Comment: I did try to pass the structures in by reference with the & operator, but my debugger stated something about I passed in an incorrect data type.  So I tried doing something like swap(&tower_1, &tower_2), but my debugger threw me an exception.  I'll try to consult another book and test my code again.

Comment: actually I dont understand if you expect `void swap_disk(disk* swap_tower_a, disk* swap_tower_b)` to swap the pointers or the pointees. Questions about non working code should include a [mcve], output and expected output.

Comment: `swap(&tower_1, &tower_2)` is not how you use references. You don't create references at the call side. You declare the function with reference parameters `void swap_disk(disk& swap_tower_a, disk& swap_tower_b)`

Comment: @JonathanIsozaki - In C++ pointers is an advanced feature that beginners don't need to use. In C they are used a lot, only because there are no other options there. Likewise, in C you *have to* implement your own lists, stacks, and swap functions. In C++ they are part of the standard library. And C++ lists and stacks know their own sizes, so you don't have to count members. It is important to learn how to use components that are available and already tested!

Comment: If you want to code the C-style way, why don't you just write plain good old C? You don't have to change much, only `std::cout` exchanging by `printf` and a few exchanged headers. Then I'd delete this question and ask the (almost) identical one tagged C, this way you get around all this (justfied!) discussion about what is idiomatic or not ;)

Comment: I'll try both styles - the C-style and C++ <stack> library.  I'll modify my code a bit.  Thank you everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is too much code there for me to give you a fix, but generally I think the problem is that you are misunderstanding what happens when you pass a pointer to a function as an argument.

In a call like`void swap_disk(disk* swap_tower_a, disk* swap_tower_b)` the pointers `swap_tower_a` and `swap_tower_b` are being passed by value, this means inside of `swap_disk` you have access to copies of the pointer values you passed in, not those variables themselves. So for example the following is not doing what you think it is doing:

```
// ...
else if (swap_tower_a != NULL && swap_tower_b == NULL)
{
    swap_tower_b = push(swap_tower_b, top_tower_a->value);
    // ...
}
```

Say `swap_tower_a` is not null and `swap_tower_b` is null, then `push` is going to return a newly allocated `disk` and that is being assigned to `swap_tower_b`  but `swap_tower_b` is just a copy of the pointer variable passed into `swap_disk`. Assigning a new value to a local copy of it will not affect the variable used by the calling code. To do that you would need `swap_disk` to either take pointers to pointers to disks or references to pointers to disks -- which is up to you, typically in C++ you use references, but you are writing very C-looking code so might prefer `disk**`.

Comment: Your answer made me realize my mistake.  Do you mind if you may please give an example with swap_disk on using references?

Comment: the signature would be
`void swap_disk(disk*& swap_tower_a, disk*& swap_tower_b)`

Comment: I also had to update the other function signatures as well, but it was the same idea.